Book series that involves the Victor brothers fighting in space
I'm trying to identify this book series. It is set in the future, and two orphans become brothers, taking the name the Victor Brothers. They join one of the local gangs and, when old enough, join the military. They end up excelling in the military and becoming crack unit commandos. until one is killed and then the other is abducted and chosen to join the Roman Legion to fight an unidentified alien threat.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a time travel story?  How does someone in the future join a Roman legion?  Is there a future Roman Empire?

Possibly the Harmony War series and Maraukian War series by Michael Chatfield? It's set in the future, about two "Victor brothers" who start out in the slums and eventually join Earth's Military Forces (EMF). By the second series only one brother appears to still be alive and is facing a new type of alien threat.

I did find a mention of "Victor brothers" in a review of book 3; can you confirm the bit about joining a legion?

I was going by the Amazon listing for Sacremon, the first entry in the series. "Stay in Earth’s slums or carve out a life in Earth’s Military Forces... Mark and his brother Tyler survived the slums... With a thirty-five year EMF contract the Victor brothers might have a new life, but it comes at a hefty cost..."
The EMF there seems to match with the military/commandos part of the OP's description, but the summary doesn't cover the entire plot so I can't tell being chosen to fight in the Roman Legion later is a match.

Going by those summaries it does appear that both brothers are still alive at least through the beginning of the last book. None of the summaries mention the Roman Legion, but the "Harmony" of the "Harmony War" series title is/are an alien threat. Apparently not unidentified though, if they have a name, so unclear if the OP is expecting a NEW alien threat at the end.

The author's Patreon has a post on the (then) upcoming Maraukian War series that references the Roman Legion: https://www.patreon.com/posts/whats-next-15461497?l=de
"I will be working on book 1 of the Maraukian War Series, think bad ass gun battles, powered armor, fighting aliens and roman Legion!"

I have found copies of the books and they do match the description. The brothers Tyler and Mark survive the five books of the Harmony War series, but in the first book of the Maraukian series Tyler is dead and Mark joins the "Roma Legion". NB "Roma" not "Roman" - Roma is a planet. Good find Mike, and welcome to the SFF SE :-)
